# how can i write comments on some cells of excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I didn't find anything that enable me to write comments on some specific cell while writing excel sheet using **panadas.to_excel** . Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching for some time, I think the best way to handle comments or other such properties like color and size of text at cell or sheet level is to use XlsxWriter with pandas.

Here is the link to the some nice examples of using XlsxWriter with pandas:

```
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html
```

Answer (score 2):

My reputation is too low to write a comment...

The [given link by Randhawa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36401133/8979290) does not provide any information about how to add comments. You can refer to this link https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_comments.html, which specifies how you can add comments with `XlsxWriter`.

```
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')
worksheet.write_comment('A1', 'This is a comment')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example based on the useful web pages linked to by [Randhawa](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) and [Carsten](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_comments.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_simple.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object (sheet)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")

# Get the xlsxwriter object for the sheet where you will write a comment 
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

# Add comment to cell A1 in worksheet ("Sheet1"), set to visible
worksheet.write_comment("A1", "This is a comment", {"visible": True})

# Write the data (sheets) to the workbook
writer.close()
```